# Python Password Validation Using Special Characters - Avoiding Regex

Tags: python, validation, passwords, verification, password-checker

relatively new to Python, but I haven't seen anything like this on SO just yet.

I am in the process of building a password validator in Python, I have already created several rules such as length, alphanumeric, caps, etc.  The portion I am hung up on is that I need a specific special character set to check for as well. I am unsure if I just have a syntax issue, or if I am not building the code check portion, but no matter what I enter, it seems to always flag the special characters as not being in the password even if they are.

I attempted to call out the special character list as follows:

```
spec= "!@#$%&_="
```

The portion doing the work is in a series of validation checks for each item (mentioned above), for the special character check I am attempting:

```
elif not any(s in spec for char in s):
            print ("Password must contain a special character of !@#$%&_=")
```

The program runs through but hits on the special character print statement even with a valid password that should pass.  I believe I am getting hung up on the elif + any in statements and the syntax is off.

NOTE: I want to avoid using regular expressions, and use the specified special character list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"[...]I have already created several rules such as length, alphanumeric, caps, etc."_ - Obligatory [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix you replace `any(s in spec for char in s)` by `any(char in spec for char in s)`.

To check if password contains at least a special character do:

```
special_character = "!@#$%&_="

def is_valid(pwd):
    global special_character
    return any(char in spec for char in pwd)    

def is_valid_other_method(pwd):
   global special_character
   return len(set(special_character).intersection(set(pwd))) > 0

print(is_valid('qwerty!'))
# True

print(is_valid('qwerty'))
# False
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!  I am attempting to insert this into my code, and I am getting the output you stated.  How do I print statement for if true print: 'password valid' or the 'password must contain at least one of the following special characters: !@#$%&_='  ... I am not getting the output to check for the special character, if it is valid to print a valid statement or to advise the user to use a special password.  It is also printing the True/False regardless if there is an error caught higher up in the code on the validation settings.  What am I missing?

Comment: I am probably not being clear - my apologies (new to StackOverflow).

I can't seem to post my code correctly in a comment. =(

Comment: I was looking to have it produce the result of (after going through the previus checks, and special character check last, that if it passes the special character check to print 'Password is valid' else print 'Password must contain a special character' ...  `if is_valid(s): 
      print("Password is valid")
else print("Password must contain at least one of the following special characters: !@#$%&_=")` but this gives me a syntax error on the 'else print' line.

Comment: It works!  I forgot the else: and not just else.  This works perfectly now, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. However, you need to implement the last function. Here is all the code you need.

```
 word = "!@#$%&&^&*"

 def true(pwd))
     global character
     return any(char in spec for char in pwd) 

 def otherthingsthatstrue(pwd):
     global character
     return len(set(character).intersection(set(pwd))) > 0

 print(true('word!')

 print(otherthingsthatstrue('word'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - and I am not sure if my brain is just fried from attempting to do this for six hours straight before asking for help, I am unfamiliar with the use of "global" and I familiarized myself with intersection, but on your second def declare I receive an error that "this code will never be reached".  It is also skipping over the special character check.  I have a funny feeling I am probably not explaining myself correctly.  I even tried to do a modification of this code using my password variable of 's' and I am getting a syntax error on 'print(otherthingsthatstrue('word'))'

Comment: A global variable lets it reach all functions because it is global for every class and definition to use.